# Структура, вложенные папки webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, config

У меня есть проект где в index.html прописаны пути к картинкам. Как в webpacke сохранить их. У меня есть папки и в них может быть картинка или вложенная папка. Вебпак почему-то игнорирует вложенные папки в которые картинка
конфиг:

```
import path from "path";
import webpack from "webpack";
import "core-js/stable";
import "webpack-dev-server";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import { CleanPlugin } from "webpack";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import OptimizeCssPlugin from "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin";
import TerserWebpackPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin";
import { Optimization } from "webpack";
import { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } from "webpack";

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const isProd = !isDev;
const filename = (ext: string) =>
  isDev ? `[name].${ext}` : `[name].[contenthash].${ext}`;

const optimization = (): Optimization => {
  const config: Optimization = {
    splitChunks: { chunks: "all" },
    runtimeChunk: "single",
  };
  if (isProd) {
    config["minimizer"] = [new OptimizeCssPlugin(), new TerserWebpackPlugin()];
  }
  return config;
};
const cssLoaders = (extra?: string) => {
  const loader = [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    },

    "css-loader",
    {
      loader: "postcss-loader",
      options: {
        postcssOptions: {
          plugins: ["postcss-preset-env"],
        },
      },
    },
  ];
  if (extra) {
    loader.push(extra);
  }
  return loader;
};

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    main: ["core-js/stable", "./ts/main.ts"],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".png"],
    alias: {
      "@models": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/modules"),
      "@": path.resolve("src"),
      style: path.resolve("src/assets/css/"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: filename("js"),
    assetModuleFilename: "[path][name][ext]",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd,
      },
    }),
    new CleanPlugin({}),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: filename("css"),
    }),
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin({}),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: cssLoaders(),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      { test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/, type: "asset/inline" },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: cssLoaders("sass-loader"),
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: optimization(),
  devServer: {
    port: "3005",
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
    hot: isDev,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    open: true,
  },
  devtool: isProd ? false : "source-map",
};
```

export default config;

Answer (score 0):

Заметил что у меня игнорировались только картинки, которые подгружались тегом img добавил html-loader и все заработало.